# Strange return value for system() with wget on Windows

Tags: c++, google-maps, powershell, google-maps-api-3, wget

I am attempting to use `wget` and `system()` to connect with the Google Maps Distance Matrix API using C++, compiling with G++. I'll put the code that seems relevant below:

```cpp
int main(){
  \\ get user input to format into a usable URL
  std::string url = url_maker(city_vector); \\ url is in ""
  int system(const char* command);
  std::string command = "wget " + url + " -o \path\to\file.txt";
  int return_val = system(command.c_str());
  std::cout<<return_val<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I execute `system("wget \"url\" -o filepath)`, I get a return value of -1073741515. However, running `"wget \"url\" -o filepath"` in PowerShell works fine.

I have confirmed that `wget` is on my path and that the URLs I am generating work. I have also read dozens of StackOverflow answers on `system()` and `wget`, tried `libcurl` and `InvokeWebRequest`, and so far nothing has worked for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you shelling out to an external process to access the URL, instead of using an embedded HTTP-capable API like [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)? If you are having trouble using it, you should ask about that, not avoid it.

Comment: The reason why `wget` works in PowerShell, but not in your program, is b/c PowerShell has an alias `wget` for `Invoke-WebRequest`. Neither the alias nor the cmdlet will work outside PowerShell. If you wanted to use them you'd need to invoke them like `powershell -Command "wget ..."` (with all the escaping headaches that come with nested quotes across different languages). I do not recommend going that route if there is a library that can be used "natively" in your code.

Comment: my experience is not to use a space between -o and the filepath
next, (windows??) try where wget.exe to make sure wget can be found.
Finally, I get sometimes a strange return (0xFFC0000374) when the command has been executed correctly (downloaded file has correct length and there are no other failures)
Why do you use \\ for comment instead of //?
Why do you expect single \ to work, that is an escape character.
So your code is well, not quite correct.